# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error. a very annoying error

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, discord

basically, it keeps on giving me that error and honestly I can't figure it out.
code:

```
    @tasks.loop(seconds=60)
    async def mutething():
        db = sqlite3.connect('mute.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT timeofmute FROM mutes")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        out = [item for t in result for item in t]
        out = [i + 60 for i in out]
        out = tuple(out)
        cursor.executemany("UPDATE mutes SET timeofmute (?)", (out,))
```

error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: Check the syntax of `UPDATE`: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing equal in your update statement but you need a where clause to pass primary key value , so you need to add your pk value to your tuple as well, so you need to include that in your select statement :

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT id, timeofmute FROM mutes")

cursor.execute("UPDATE mutes SET timeofmute= ? WHERE id = ?", (out,))
```

but you simply could update data using sql without fetching the whole data :

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def mutething():
    db = sqlite3.connect('mute.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"UPDATE mutes SET timeofmute = timeofmute + 60")
```

Comment: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.

Comment: I want to update every "timeofmute" value in the table though.

Comment: is it possible to add a number instead of a date.

Comment: @Not_GG_Gamer yes, I thought it's datetime column , see updated answer